# How to know in JMeter that how many Number of Threads(users) have been executed out of given Number of Threads(users)?

Tags: jmeter

My Test Plan is as Follow:

```
Test Plan 
 HTTP Cookie Manager
 CSV Data Set Config
Thread Group
 login request
 J Spring Security Authentication request
 3rd request
 4th request
 5th request
```

I set username and password of 75 unique users in CSV Data set Config file and pass as parameter in login request.
i set Number of Threads(users)=75 and Ramp-up Period=25 means 3 users per second scenario.

When i run the test in non gui i noticed all 75 users active and running as in below image:[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSjQT.png)

After completion of test when i review the html report and section "Active Threads Over Time" it shows only 62 active threads.
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAkpy.png)

My question is why jmeter report didn't show the remain 13 users?
Please advise where i can see the total number of threads(users) active and running successfully.thanks.

Comment: Have you configured `Save active thread counts` as mentioned in this link https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/#Configure-JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, all your 75 records with user's data were consumed by 62 threads.

I, honestly, don't get why you've been looking at these threads over time instead of measuring how your requests are doing.

And overall endeavor seem to be quite a mess (in given description, at least).

First of all - what were your aim for the load to be created?
Numbers, come up with numbers, please!

Did you want to keep some steady avg. request per second pace during some period?
What are these numbers, then?
What's the distribution? Even? Random? Gaussian?
etc, etc

Then, again - what are you measuring at the end?

Not having these questions answered, you end up with that chaos you have.

Like: `Number of Threads(users)=75 and Ramp-up Period=25 means 3 users per second scenario` - no, it doesn't, even your own screenshot shows you that (9.4 rps overall, that's what you have)

Comment: I think my question is simple but you take it another way. I simple want to know how many users successfully completed each request from give user number 75. In the report its confusing me by showing 62 active thread.
Secondly my aim is to find out how much requests/sec my app can support. For finding that i started from 3 requests/sec and later goes up but in first instance i discover that my all users are not successfully run.

Comment: But that IS in my answer: if you want to know " how many users successfully completed each request" - why are you looking at the damned threads instead? Look at the results!

Comment: Then, you DID NOT start from 3rps, because you didn't configure it that way - that's what I'm saying.

Comment: And last but not least: your question is simple in scope of your misunderstanding of the very concept of how JMeter works. If you adamant in that - then sorry, I personally can't help you with that case.